# Error configuracion socket phpMyAdmin - Kali linux

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, socket

INFORMACIÓN DEL SISTEMA:

-GNU LINUX / KALI
-amd64

Hola.

Tengo un problema al intentar entrar a phpMyAdmin, y por lo que veo es sobre la configuración del socket.
[image: Error aparece luego de ingresar usuario y contraseña]

sin embargo e intentado reparar poniendo está dirección (qué es la que encontré en la mayoría de los foros).

[image: he puesto la dirección que encuentro generalmente en foros de internet]

al buscar el fichero para editar el vinculo "php.ini", me encuentro con la siguiente sorpresa, hay más de uno. ¿Cual tengo que editar?

[image: utilizo comando locate para buscar el dichero php.ini]

Inlcuso si agrego la dirección a todos los ficheros que aparecen, sigue apareciendo el error.

Espero me puedan ayudar. Quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: Te recomendaría revisar el php.ini :p. Especificamente el que tienes en la 2da imagen el de la ruta que comprende cli. Claro antes de editarlo mejor copiar y pegar en el escritorio el original así si dañas algo utilizas ese archivo de respaldo.

Comment: @Huskie , eso hago amifo, pero que es lo que tengo que revisar? ... que es lo que causa el error?

Comment: Puede que el puerto que intenta utilizar mysql esté ocupado por alguna otra aplicación. No he trabajado con esta distro antes pero buscando en  internet sale que para ver los puertos ocupados puedes utilizar en la terminal el siguiente comando: `nmap -sT -O localhost`

Comment: Si mysql sale en los puertos mostrados entonces si está activo en tu localhost sino hay que cambiar el puerto de mysql en el archivo php.ini donde dice `mysqli.default_port=3306` con el valor de otro puerto. Ejemplo `mysqli.default_port=5123`

Comment: Luego das un reinicio al servicio de mysql y pruebas nuevamente en tu localhost y debería solucionarse. Ojo si ves a mysql en los puertos cuando ejecutes `nmap` entonces este no es el problema. Fijate si está ocupado el puerto 3306 por otra aplicación ya que es este puerto el utilizado por defecto para mysql